задали дз. попросили написать тернарный оператор и if else на С что бы не делал пишет ошибки
Вот весь код.
#include <stdio.h>

// Тернарный оператор
char result = (num > 0) ? "Больше 0" : "Меньше 0";

// if-else
char* result;
if (num > 0) {
    result = "Больше 0";
} else {
    result = "Меньше 0";
}

Ошибки которые он выдаёт:
1.идентификатор "num" не определен (строка 4)
2.выражение должно иметь константное значение (строка 4)
3.требуется объявление (строка 8)

Ну так у вас переменная num не определена... Об этом у вас говорят как раз 2 ошибки

А почему у вас в первом случае result имеет тип char, а во втором — char*? И, кстати, const char *, раз уж вы присваиваете строковый литерал...

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO!  рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Для начала, если бы вы внимательно посмотрели хотя бы на одну программу из учебника, то наверняка бы заметили, что она должна иметь как минимум одну функцию -- int main () { ...}  (именно с нее начинается исполнение программы...) (а вообще, настоятельно советую прочесть K&R (там всего пара сотен страниц) перед тем, как задавать очередной вопрос на подобную тему тут)

И ведь вам всё правильно подсказывает. Переменная num к примеру откуда вдруг взялась, она же не описана.

Ни разу не писал ничего на C. Но разобрав ваш пример, мне показалось странным что вы пытаетесь сохранить в переменную типа char строку которая во всех языках программирования может хранить только один символ. То есть вы пытаетесь запихнуть например больше 0 в переменную которая может хранить только один символ, например "а"
Вместо этого используйте указатель на строку.
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num = 5;

    const char* result;
    if (num > 0) {
        result = "Больше 0";
    } else {
        result = "Меньше 0";
    }

    printf("%s\n", result);
    return 0;
}

С использованием тернарного оператора это будет выглядеть так:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num = 5; // ваше значение 

    // Тернарный оператор
    const char* result = (num > 0) ? "Больше 0" : "Меньше 0";

    printf("%s\n", result);
    return 0;
}



Если на компьютере не отлаживали, то для первого раза на Си просто отлично!
